# ServiceMix -> NetBeans OpenESB?

Tags: apache, netbeans, apache-servicemix, open-esb

I've picked up a project that needs to import some (old) JBI components that were developed using ServiceMix about three years ago. I need to bring these into to a modern GlassFish environment. So far, it's not very clear what or how I should do it. Any tips or pointers?

My worst case scenario is to wrap the JBI component call in a POJO class, stripping out the ServiceMix bits, to see if that will at least get the gears spinning again.

I note elsewhere, that the JBI code in ServiceMix is not apparently JBI certified. So maybe that might be an indication this may be a non-sequitur.

TIA!
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I would think and re-think and then re-think once more before moving or importing anything into open esb. OpenESB project has basically been left without funding since Oracle bought Sun.

Answer (score 0):

I did one better. I wrote my own data flow processing system from scratch. Everything else available was just too heavyweight and complex.

My new system, code named LightRail, works great. All connectivity is component driven and defined through a single JSON configuration file. All processing and flow control is handled through a single BeanShell script.

I've already deployed 10 different data flows in the last 10 months, connecting to IMAP, SFTP, FTP, Files and a database or two. Life is good again...

Andrew